# If $v_0\in\mathrm{hull}(v_0,\ldots,v_n)^\circ$ then $v_0\in\mathrm{hull}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

Let $v_0,\ldots,v_n\in\Bbb R^d$ be vectors, $\operatorname{hull}$ denote the convex hull, and $\operatorname{Int}$ denote the topological interior, then suppose $$v_0\in\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{hull}(v_0,\ldots,v_n)).$$ It seems intuitive to me that we would then have that $$v_0\in\operatorname{hull}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$$ but why is this true (assuming it is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that that the vectors are distinct.  Also without loss of generality (i.e. up to a translation of the convex hull), suppose that $v_0 = \vec 0$.  Now, note that if $0$ is in the interior of $\operatorname{hull}(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n)$, then there exist $\lambda_i \geq 0$ with  $\sum \lambda_i = 1$ and $\lambda_0 \neq 1$ such that 
$$
\lambda_0 0 + \lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n = 0 \implies\\
\lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n = 0
$$
Now, let $\mu_i = \lambda_i\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)^{-1}$.  Then $\sum_i \mu_i = 1$, and 
$$
\mu_1 v_1 + \cdots + \mu_n v_n = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)^{-1}(\lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)^{-1}(0) = 0
$$
So, we see that $0 \in \operatorname{hull}(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, as desired.

---

To see that we can express $0$ as a convex combination with $\lambda_0 \neq 0$, note that:

- $0$ is in the interior of the convex hull.  So, there is an open neighborhood about $0$ contained in the convex hull.
- So, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, $-\epsilon v_1$ is in the convex hull.
- So, $0$ can be expressed as a convex combination of $-\epsilon v_1$ and $v_1$, which is in turn a convex combination of $v_0,v_1\dots,v_n$ with $\lambda_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: But why can we choose that $\lambda_0\ne1$?

Comment: Here's an argument that works: $0$ is in the interior of the convex hull.  So, there is an open neighborhood about $0$ contained in the convex hull.  So, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, $-\epsilon v_1$ is in the convex hull.  $0$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $-\epsilon v_1$ and $v_1$.

Comment: That tells me that $0$ is in the affine span of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. But why is it in the convex hull?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine sorry, of course I meant a *convex combination* of $-\epsilon v_1$ and $v_1$.  In particular,
$$
0 = \frac 1{1 + \epsilon}(-\epsilon v_1) + \frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}v_1
$$

Answer (score 2):

To quote Wikipedia (most reliable source there is xD):

> the interior of a subset S of points of a topological space X consists of all points of S that do not belong to the boundary of S

So, it $v_0 \in Int(S)$, that means $v_0$ is in $S$ but it is not on the boundary os $S$. Specifically, $Int(S) \subset S \therefore \forall x \in Int(S), x \in S$. Your intuition is correct.

You can imagine this as some random polygon. The polygon contains all points strictly inside of it and all points on its border. The interior of the polygon contains all points strictly inside of it. If a point is an interior point of the polygon, then it is strictly inside of the polygon, and is in the polygon itself as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to bring me closer to a proof though. The only idea I've had so far that seems vaguely promising is to consider the polygon as a simplicial complex, using the (unique) minimal convexly-generating set as the set of vertices, but this isn't quite enough to give me a proof.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine I'm sorry; I can't quite understand your comment. You definitely know more about this subject than I do, but from what I could learn on my own, this is what I could gather to give some insight as to why this makes sense. As for a concrete mathematically sound proof, I'm afraid I don't have one.

Comment: I've proved the following lemma: for any convex hull $P$ of a finite set of points in $\Bbb R^d$, there exists a set $V\subset\Bbb R^d$ that has convex hull $P$, and is contained in any other finite set $V'$ with convex hull $P$.

Comment: Now, if I can show that any such convex hull is simply made up of simplices with vertices from $V$ glued at the faces, then by compactness of the convex hull, I have a proof. However, in order to prove this, I must prove that any convex hull of a finite set of points has a decomposition as a simplicial complex using those very same vertices.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine Interesting concepts. I'm afraid I'll have to review/study this subject more before I could help you further then. Shall I delete my answer if it doesn't offer you the proof you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: first you should assume $n \ge 1$ otherwise that's not true!

According to the definition of extreme points observe that
$$\rm ext ~( conv(v_0 , v_1, ..., v_n  ) ) \subseteq  \{ v_0 , v_1, ..., v_n \}  $$

Since $v_0$ is an interioir point then it cannot be an extreme point so

$$\rm ext ~( conv(v_0 , v_1, ..., v_n  ) ) \subseteq  \{   v_1, ..., v_n \}  $$

$$\rm conv~ [ ext ~( conv(v_0 , v_1, ..., v_n  ) )] \subseteq \rm conv \{ v_1, ..., v_n \}  $$

$$ \rm conv(v_0 , v_1, ..., v_n  )  \subseteq \rm conv \{ v_1, ..., v_n \}  $$
DONE.

This proof shows only if $v_0$ is not a extreme (vertex) point then claim still holds.

Comment: The assertion is also true for $n = 0$, since $v_0 \in \operatorname{Int}\operatorname{conv}\{v_0\}$ cannot be true (unless $d = 0$).